# Understanding abstract factory Generic Implementation

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading Andrei Alexandrescu's Modern C++ Design and come across some thing:

Here is how Generic `AbstractFactory` looks like

```
template <class T>
class AbstractFactoryUnit
{
public:
    virtual T* DoCreate(Type2Type<T>) = 0;
    virtual ~AbstractFactoryUnit() {}
};

template 
<
    class TList,
    template <class> class Unit = AbstractFactoryUnit
>
class AbstractFactory : public GenScatterHierarchy<TList, Unit>
{
public:
    typedef TList ProductList;
    template <class T> T* Create()
    {
        Unit <T>& unit = *this;
        return unit.DoCreate(Type2Type<T>());
    }
};
```

Now suppose we have three classes:

```
class Soldier { };
class Monster { };
class SuperMonster { };
```

and define the following type definition:

```
typedef AbstractFactory
<
    TYPELIST_3(Soldier, Monster, SuperMonster)
>
AbstractEnemyFactory;
```

Then, in the Alexandrescu's `Modern C++ Design` said:

> You can automatically convert a reference to an `AbstractEnemyFactory`
>   to a reference to an `AbstractFactory<Soldier>`, `AbstractFactory`
>   `<Monster>`, or `AbstractFactory<SuperMonster>`.

Might it just a typo and he meant `AbstractFactoryUnit<Soldier>` and so forth...

Because to me it's not clear how we can convert a reference to `AbstractEnemyFactory` to `AbstractFactory<Soldier>`

Comment: Yes, it is a typo and I think it is listed in the [errata](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/errata/) (where it says `AbstractFactory` -> `AFUnit` and `AFUnit` -> `AbstractFactoryUnit` in two different entries).

Comment: @DanielFrey Seems you're right, thank you. It just blow up my mind for a bit.